# V4L2 doesn't use a lower advertised frame rate

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, v4l2

I'm capturing images on Linux (Pi 3B+, Stretch lite). The camera reports that it's capable of delivering images at 30 fps or 60 fps. Here's the output from `v4l2-ctl`

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'YU12'
        Name        : Planar YUV 4:2:0
                Size: Discrete 640x512
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'Y16 '
        Name        : 16-bit Greyscale
                Size: Discrete 640x512
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)

        Index       : 2
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'NV12'
        Name        : Y/CbCr 4:2:0
                Size: Discrete 640x512
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)

        Index       : 3
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: ''
        Name        : 3132564e-0000-0010-8000-00aa003
                Size: Discrete 640x512
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
```

But if I try to change to 30fps:

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-parm=30 --set-fmt-video=width=640,height=512,pixelformat="Y16 " --stream-mmap --stream-count=240 --stream-to=video.raw
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 59.40 fps
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 59.70 fps
```

The framerate is simply ignored.

I can verify this using `usbmon` (awesome tool):

Capturing at 60:

```
Bus ID 1 (USB bus number 1)     To device       From device
  Device ID 1 :                 0.00 kb/s       0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 2 :                 0.00 kb/s       0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 3 :                 0.00 kb/s       0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 4 :                 0.00 kb/s       0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 6 :                 155.67 kb/s     39075.21 kb/s
```

Capturing at "30":

```
Bus ID 1 (USB bus number 1)     To device       From device
  Device ID 1 :                 0.00 kb/s       0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 2 :                 0.00 kb/s       0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 3 :                 0.00 kb/s       0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 4 :                 0.00 kb/s       0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 6 :                 148.34 kb/s     39056.18 kb/s
```

This is consistent with 640x512x2x60 = 39.3 MB per sec.

The problem is that if the camera is forcing itself to use 60fps, it's allocating more bus bandwidth than it needs to (and other cameras won't run because they claim there's not enough bandwidth spare). So while I can throttle the stream, at a hardware level it doesn't help.

Gstreamer doesn't seem to work either, but I guess because it's using V4L2 for capture. For example:

```
timeout 15s gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=GRAY16_LE,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! filesink location=video_30.raw
```

Are there any other video backends I can try? Or is there a better way to set the framerate?

Comment: I would compile v4l-utils with debug prints, specifically checking that the ioctl `VIDIOC_S_PARM` was successful.